# Converting a string to decimal and comparing with Linq to NHibernate 3.1

Tags: linq, nhibernate, type-conversion, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a table like:

```
Name     Height
-------  ---------
Sam      "1.80"
Paul     "1.79"
Max      "1.81m"
Steve    "none"
```

I want to filter only the peoples with height > 1.79.
To do this, I must convert to decimal and then compare. Ignoring the values ​​that are not numerical, such as "none".
I tryed Decimal.Parse() and Convert.ToDecimal() but show a error System.NotSupportedException

```
peoples = peoples.Where(f => Convert.ToDecimal(f.Height) > 1.8);
peoples = peoples.Where(f => decimal.Parse(f.Height) > 1.8);
```

Any solution??

Tks[]

Patrick Coelho

Comment: Why do you want to store Height as a string in database? It should be more convinient to store it as a float. Then the problem you have will disappear.

Comment: @StuffHappens: This is from a legacy database.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you will be able to compare the non-numeric values in the database against a number using NH.Linq is either:

1. Convert the column to a numeric column
2. Load all the values up and compare in memory (which is not recommended for big datasets.

Comment: This table have 50K records. Impossible.